# Access to Tabhost objects in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

I have created some new tabs with new contents in a Tabhost and I want to access to their children to edit.

I have used this code for getting all objects in Tabhost but it doesn't give the current objects in Tabhost but objects that I have created in my project initially.

```
int cnt = host.getTabContentView().getChildCount();
    for ( int j=0 ; j<cnt ; j++ ) {
        System.out.println( "\nChild " + j + " : \n" );
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) (host.getTabContentView().getChildAt(j));

        final int childcount = ll.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childcount; i++) {
            View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
            System.out.println(v.getId());
            System.out.println(v.toString());
        }
    }
```

I want to get access to current existed objects in TabHost. Please, Can you help me ?

Comment: Do you mean that "LinearLayout ll" is object that was in the tabHost but you replaces him and it still return the old view?

Comment: @yotam As I understood the concept of TabHost, We can create some initaial Tabs but they will not shown in Tabhost until we add them by code. So I have created 3 Tabs initially but I didn't added them to TabHost and I have created some new Tabs by [this code](http://pastebin.com/WL6pJbp6). Actually I want to access the EditTexts in dynamically created tabs but I don't know how! The above code returns initial created 3 Tabs !!!